# Hovering Dialogue Box

Tags: java, styling

I am creating a log in form in Java.  I have already completed the entire structure of the program, as well, I have designed it's purpose and perfected it's functionality.  However, now I am focusing on styling the program.  I'm proud of it as it is and it's fine if I don't add this feature, however I really would like to and cannot discover how.

In summary, when a username is typed into the login form, I have a void that runs after the JTextField loses focus.  This void searches for possible invalid characters such as spaces.  I can successfully change the color of the border on my JTextField, and other attributes I wish to change, however I also would like to have a small dialogue box to hover over the JTextField to say what specifically is wrong with what was typed.  (e.g. "Your username cannot contain spaces!").

Ideally, it would be a rectangle that could simply be filled with text, and only appear when the username is deemed incorrect, and be able to disappear when it is fixed ( I can handle the appearance and disappearance most likely, I just need help with creating this box thing ).

Is there any such thing as like a "JHoverBox" or something that I could add to my JTextField?

Comment: Why hover? Just add a label that's normally empty near the text field and fill it with a message when the user needs help.  I usually do this in red to attract his/her attention.

Comment: I thought of this idea too, however I have this vision in my mind, and if worst comes to worst, I'll do a simple JLabel, but I would prefer a hover-dingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can have, as Gene said, a label that's normally empty near the text field, but you can have it coloured like the background colour. This will make the user not able to see it, and when you detect something wrong, you can change the colour and add the text. Simple!

Comment: But i would prefer to not use a JLabel, as i responded to Gene.